# Plaintext and ciphertext block sizes

Tags: rsa

How can you determine the largest plaintext block size and smallest ciphertext size if you used RSA with $n=59768553302699443$ using an alphabet with $27$ characters?

Comment: Both plaintexts and ciphertexts have an upper bound of $n-1$.

Comment: ok, so how would I go about calculating them? Isit correct to say that if m is the ciphertext block size, it can be calculated as 27^m<n?

Comment: Be warned that this question is only valid for **toy ciphers** that use **raw / textbook** RSA. You'd better use AOEP and a large key size for solving actual RSA problems.

Answer (score 3):

With an alphabet of 27 characters, the maximum number of characters that can fit into one plaintext block is equal to the largest integer less than or equal to $\text{log}(n) / \text{log}(27)$:

$$\bigg\lfloor\frac{\text{log}(59768553302699443)}{\text{log(27)}}\bigg\rfloor = 11$$

On the other hand, assuming the ciphertext is represented as a string of characters in the same alphabet, the minimum ciphertext length will be 12. This is because it will have to accommodate a maximum value of $n$, which is greater than $27^{11}$.